# String to Date e.g. Jan 58 to 1958-01-01

Tags: sql

I want to turn a short date in varchar into a date:
'Short month name - YY' format such as `'Apr-57'` or `'Mar-2001'` to an readable format for MSMS to turn it into a date such as `1957-04-01` or `2001-03-01`.

Is there a shortcut I am missing? I've tried to convert, cast, and substring to alter the format to see if it would help. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Please tag your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
DECLARE @vc VARCHAR(50) = 'Mar-2001';
SET @VC = '01-' + @vc;
SELECT CAST(@VC AS DATE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My next problem is that I need to use it in an update statement in order to correct any in the format such as above. How would I go about doing this? I'm familiar with update statements however not using variables. Thank you again!

Comment: assuming your field that has the "mmm-yyyy" data in it is called f1, and your date field is d1, then something like this should work:   
UPDATE tbl1 
SET d1 = CAST(('01-' + F1)) AS DATE);

Answer (score 0):

If it is always in the same format then you can try the below. I have tested it on SQL server.

```
DECLARE @unformat_date varchar(10) = 'May-2001'

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR,REPLACE(@unformat_date,'-',' ')),DATEPART(MONTH,REPLACE(@unformat_date,'-',' ')),01) as formated_dated
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm just trying to work out if it will work in all instances of such as Apr-57 etc. Thank you!